# Implementation of a manual SSL-handshake

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, javacard

I need some help with implementing a manual ssl handshake between an android smartphone and a server.
The background why is in my case the encryption/decryption of the communication. Android would be just a proxy which should have no information about what data is exchanged between the server and my javacard applet which only can communicate with the android device.

My first thought was to establich a connection to a server like a normal http just on the ssl port of the server: (in android)

```
Socket socket = new Socket("google.de", 443);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
// send data for the handshake
os.writeChars("Params for the SSL handshake");
// read the server response
in.read(...)
// answer with the next ssl handshake step
....
```

and then send the information for the handshake and wait for the response.
Problem here is, I don't know in which format I would have to send the parameters (like the client hello: protocolVersion, random, sessionID, cipherSuites, compressMethod). Or if it would work?

The other way I inspected was the

> javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

which makes the handshake by itself. 
For example:

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    // getDefault();
    final SSLSocketFactory fac = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    final SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) fac.createSocket("google.de", 443);

    socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {

        @Override
        public void handshakeCompleted(final HandshakeCompletedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Cipher:" + event.getCipherSuite());
        }
    });
    final String[] ciphers = fac.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    final String[] protocols = { "TLSv1" };
    final SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters(ciphers, protocols);
    params.setNeedClientAuth(false);
    socket.setSSLParameters(params);
    socket.startHandshake();
 }
```

In this case, all the relevant security information (like the secret exchange) and so on will happen on Android... (in detail: in the SSLSocket itself I think) That's exactly the way I don't want!

I want to have the possibility to send the handshake parameters by my own to the server and can catch the response from the server and will forward it to my javacard applet. I know I have to take care of the encryption later on by myself.

I hope my problem is understandable and the background why I need this too. Else please give a small hint and I will do my best to complete the information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why? Just write a transparent byte-copying proxy. No need to reimplement the wheel, and it would be a major, major task.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but what will be send through this proxy? For creating a SSL connection a handshake have to be done and I don't know what kind of format I have to send all the informations.